# Magento 1.9 How to remove index in the url when login from checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

How to **remove index** in the **url** when login from **checkout**

```
checkout/onepage/index/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change url you can set permanent redirect for that from **catalog->URL Rewrite Management** :

**Requested path**

```
checkout/onepage/index/
```

**Target Path**

```
checkout/onepage/
```

Comment: thanks working but can we change in code level?

Comment: yes you can change it but it would have large impact and may be you encounter some issues with other modules ( i.e 3rd party like conversion, mailchimp etc )